# Modify Devise to check for permission to register?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, user-registration

My app has a `Permission` model and `permissions` table with an `email` field. Existing users (`User` model) can add the email addresses of people who they would like to invite to view their information. Those email addresses are stored in the `permissions.email` field in the database.

How do I go about modifying Devise's registration process so that it only allows people with an email address in the `permissions` table to create an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did this before with a validator on the user model; e.g.

```
validates :email, :my_access_control => true
```

and then create something like this

```
class MyAccessControlValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if ... not in permissions table.. 
      ... add to objects error collection why they cannot register
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if a registered user changes their email address?

Comment: Thanks, I just added `:on => :create` so that it won't run the validation during updates.